# Laravel Blade, Escape {{ }} Echo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, escaping, laravel-blade

I have a textarea tag that I wish to have a default value = {{"example text area"}}

I'm trying to do that with:

`<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">{{"example text area"}}</textarea>`
 So the output value is exactly {{"example text area"}}

But thw code above will only print `example text area`

I tried `{!!'&#123;&#123;"tre"&#125;&#125;'!!}` and the same response above, I also tried `{!!'{{"example text area"}}'!!}` and it outputs `<?php echo e("example text area"); ?>`

so how to do it?

Comment: `<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">{{'&#123;&#123;"example text area"&#125;&#125;'}}</textarea>` will print exactly your output `{{"example text area"}}`

Comment: no it prints example text area only, I need the text to be surrounded by {{ }}

Comment: tested on laravel blade and it has output with braces and string

Comment: you can also remove echo braces if you are not printing a variable like `<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">&#123;&#123;"example text area"&#125;&#125;</textarea>` it will output the same as before

Comment: same problem, as @lizeshakya said it is a bug in Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a variable inside the blade and echoing the variable where necessary like:

//test.blade.php

```
@php
    $placeholder = "{{example text area}}";
@endphp
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">{{$placeholder}}</textarea>
```

Simple way would be to echo the necessary value like

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo "{{example text area}}" ?></textarea>
```

If you Laravel Version is greater than 5.1, you can use

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">@{{"gitHub_validation"|translate}}</textarea>
```

Comment: None of them worked, first one outputs `<?php echo e(example text area); ?>`, the second produces a parse error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'`, the third outputs nothing

Comment: You need a default value with `"` `"` as well ?

Comment: yes, actually the real text i want to print is {{"gitHub_validation"|translate}}

Comment: well this will print only gitHub_validation"|translate but I need it surrounded by {{ }}, this is the problem

Comment: In my local machine, it is working fine. Unable to track the problem in yours. Give this command `php artisan view:clear` a try

Comment: same problem, my Laravel version is 5.4, Do you think that might be the problem

Comment: For simple testing only, From the https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15340, it says to comment app.js script file. Try giving it to yours. Still I am unaware of the problem it arose

Comment: unfortunately the app depends on it, I'll try something else thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this? If the text doesn't come from crontroller (variable) you can type what you want.

```html
<textarea class="form-control">my default text</textarea>
```

Or, with a placeholder if matters:

```html
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="bla"></textarea>
```

Comment: actually this is a dummy example, the data actually comes from the controller by reading a file, I view some html code and enable the user to edit it

Comment: Ok, you should have mentioned this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this? if it is static value so you can print them out.

```
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo '{{"gitHub_validation"|translate}}' ?></textarea>
```

Comment: It results in gitHub_validation only, it's a bug with Laravel 5.4  github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15340 as @lizeshakya described